# Java get xml elements value using xpath "And"

Tags: java, xml, xpath, conditional-statements

My question is as follows:

I'm using xpath to get the values i need in the XML.
**How do i get a value that has 2 conditions**?

e.g. BOOK[UIM_LEVEL_TYPE='AAA'] and [UIM_SUB_REC_TYPE='BBB']- doesn't work..
Whats the the correct way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with `BOOK[UIM_LEVEL_TYPE='AAA' and UIM_SUB_REC_TYPE='BBB']`?  Or, for that matter, `BOOK[UIM_LEVEL_TYPE='AAA'][UIM_SUB_REC_TYPE='BBB']`